# Calling Powershell script from CMD with paths as parameters

Tags: powershell, cmd, path, parameter-passing

I`m having trouble make this cmd command to run powershell script by passing two parameters (paths).

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>powershell -command \"C:\Apps\Scripts\Test\testing.ps1" \"\\Data1\dataholder$\office\J Smith\backup\" \"\\Data1\dataholder$\office\J Smith\backup2\"
```

I`m getting the error below:

```
At line:1 char:36
+ ... ps\Scripts\Test\testing.ps1 "\\Data1\dataholder$\office\ ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\\Data1\dataholder$\office' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:146
+ ... Smith\backup" "\\Data1\dataholder$\office\J Smith\backup2"
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Any idea of why this is failing?

I had to modify the path leading to script. Now the command look like that:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>powershell -command \"C:\Apps\Scripts\Power test\testing.ps1" \"\\Data1\dataholder$\office\J Smith\backup\" \"\\Data1\dataholder$\office\J Smith\backup2\"
```

This is failing due to the space in the script path, any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Your first quote escape is unnecessary `\"C:\Apps\Scripts\Test\testing.ps1"` --> `"C:\Apps\Scripts\Test\testing.ps1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to backslash escape quotes that you want to be sent from cmd shell to PowerShell:

```
powershell -command "& \"C:\Apps\Scripts\Power test\testing.ps1\" \"\\Data1\dataholder$\office\J Smith\backup\" \"\\Data1\dataholder$\office\J Smith\backup2\""
```

If your program or script file has spaces, you need to call it with a call operator (`&`) and include that in your string that is sent to `-Command`. Notice the double quotes around the entire value/string that maps to `-Command`.

**Note:** Inner double quotes work here because `$` is succeeded by `\`. If you had `dataholder$folder` as an example, you would need single quotes or to escape the `$` because PowerShell would try to interpret `$folder` as a variable.

Comment: Thank you, how to handle the space in the path leading to script? C:\Apps\Scripts\Power test\testing.ps1

Comment: I edited it to show how to do that. You need to use the call operator `&`, surround the entire command in quotes, then escape inner double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a backquoting the spaces approach.

```
type "my script.ps1"

echo $args[0]


powershell .\my` script.ps1 hi` there

hi there
```

Or strategic placement of single quotes.  Something can be executed if the first character isn't a quote.  The quote didn't work before the backslash.

```
powershell .\'my script.ps1' 'hi there'

hi there
```